# Git: clone/initialize repository without actually downloading data?

Tags: git

Let's consider you have several large LFS repositories and you want to write a small shell script for initializing these repositories on new machines in order to save users from typos and manually cloning repositories.

However, since these repositories can be quite big in terms of memory usage, you do not want the shell script to actually download any data or history. This should be done by users as soon as they *need* the data of a specific repository.

What would be the cleanest way to achieve this?

My first idea was to create each directory in the script with `mkdir` and then initializing empty Git repositories and adding remotes:

```
mkdir -p repo-path
cd repo-path
git init
git remote add repo-url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be enough if you really don't want to download anything: init and remote are local commands only.

---

If you want/can, you might initialize those repositories with a [`git clone --depth=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443509/6309), in order to have more elements.
But that would indeed download some data (not the large LFS part though)

Or, as in [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 1973](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1973#issuecomment-282048898)

```
GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git clone git@something.something.git
```

Or

```
git lfs clone git@something.something.git -X "*.*"
```